# Azure Search: How to specify search fields in v11

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

In v10 of Azure Search SDK, I was able to specify exactly which fields to search in an index by taking advantage of [SearchParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters?view=azure-dotnet) class. In v11, I see there is [SearchOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchoptions?view=azure-dotnet), but the [SearchFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchoptions.searchfields?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Search_Documents_SearchOptions_SearchFields) parameter is get only. In v10, [SearchFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.searchfields?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_SearchFields) has a setter.

How do I choose which fields to search on in v11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `.Add()` on the `SearchFields` property:

```cs
var options = new SearchOptions();
options.SearchFields.Add("field1");
options.SearchFields.Add("field2");
```

Or you can use C#'s list initializer syntax:

```cs
var options = new SearchOptions() { SearchFields = { "field1", "field2" } };
```

Example adapted from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13875).

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I wish the setter was there. I'm passing a list to a method as a parameter without knowing the exact count of search fields. It seems my only option is to iterate over this list and call `.Add()`. Previously, I used to set it to `SearchFields`.